# How to configure nginx to serve from file based on cookie

Tags: nginx, cache, ruby-on-rails

I am working on an ecommerce platform that has dynamic content for logged in users, but for logged out users many pages such as product pages and category pages are relatively static.

Rails has been configured to save copies of specific logged out pages to disk when accessed.

I would like nginx to serve these files when it detects a logged out user. We have a cookie set on users when they are logged in, so my hope was that I could check for this.

My 'ideal' nginx configuration would look something like (in a server block):

```
location /my_location { 
    if (!$cookie_user_logged_in) { 
        try_files /cached_pages/$uri /cached_pages/$uri.html $uri $uri/index.html $uri.html @rails_application; 
    } 
}
```

However, that is not valid, because as far as I can tell, based on research and error messages, one cannot put try_files inside an if.

**Is there a way to accomplish this with nginx?**

I have been told that I should do this with another tool such as Varnish. I also know that I could do things with action caching in Rails, and fragment caching to get close to the same end. However, I would like to determine if this is a viable option before adding to the tech stack or investing further in development.

Comment: Don't use if with try_files. Read this https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried using try_files inside if, but the code below works for me.
Basically, it replicates the php-fpm connection inside that specific location {} if the cookie test is successful. It allows unauthenticated access to admin-ajax.php, and denies unauth access to everything else in /wp-admin/

Further down the config file there is a `location ~\.php {...}` block which handles php requests generally.

```
        location ~ /wp-admin/ {
            set $adminok 0;
            if ($http_cookie ~* "admincookie" ) {
                    set $adminok  1;
            }
            if ($request_filename ~* "admin-ajax.php" ) {
                    set $adminok  1;
            }
            if ($adminok != 1) {
                    return 403;
            }
            include fastcgi_params;
            if (-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                    set $doc $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            }
            if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                    set $doc $document_root/wp-admin/index.php ;
            }
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $doc ;
            fastcgi_pass unix:$server_unix_socket ;
            fastcgi_cache_bypass 1;
        }
```